# Unexpected Output Type From decltype

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been experimenting with `decltype`, trying to figure out the potential benefits of it. I ran this very simple function:

```
template<class T, class U>
auto MyFunc(T t, U u) -> decltype(t < u ? t : u)
{
  return t < u ? t : u;
}
```

when calling the function:

```
auto d = MyFunc(3,3.5);

std::cout << d<<'\n';
std::cout<<"type: "<<typeid(d).name();
```

I get the following result:

```
3
type: d
```

My question is why the returned type is `d` (decimal) not `i` (integer)? Thanks!

Comment: Surprisingly an almost exact duplicate question was asked a few days ago

Comment: @Borgleader, the link you suggested answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return two different types depending on the values of the input. Therefore it choses the widest compatible type, here `double`

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not dynamically look up the types in this context. It needs to create the template instance so it chooses the most suitable type, which is `double` because if it would choose `int`, there might be a data loss conversion from `double` to `int` if it would be the case.